# Plotting maps on R readShapePoly()

Tags: r, plot, r-maptools

im trying to import a shapefile to R using the function `readShapePoly()` on package maptools, but it output this error:

> Error en .asSpatialPolygonsShapes(Map$Shapes, IDs, proj4string = proj4string,  : 
>     Not polygon shapes

What can i do?, why it happens?

Thanks!

Comment: It´s saying they aren´t polygon shapes. Are you trying to import a country political border? There is an even easier way of doing this using [gadm´s web page](http://gadm.org/country). Try to elaborate more your question, so it´s easier to help you.

Comment: Have you tried `maptools::readShapeSpatial`?

Comment: Maybe your shapefile is lines or points? Have you tried `package:rgdal` and `readOGR`, which will also read the projection data.